# AspectJ: How to pick the execution of non-annotated methods of subclasses of a given class?

Tags: aspectj, java, aop

I'd like to intercept the execution of non-annotated methods of any subclass of a given class.

For instance, say I have class `Base`:

```
public class Base {
   public void baseMethod() { //shouldn't be intercepted
      // do whatever...
   }
}
```

And, eventually, someone extends `Base`. Whatever is the new class name, its methods with some annotation `@LeaveItAlone` should not be intercepted. All the other methods of the subclass should.

```
public class Sub extends Base {
   public void interceptedMethod1() {
      // ...
   }

   public void interceptedMethod2() {
      // ...
   }

   @LeaveItAlone
   public void NOTinterceptedMethod1() {
      // ...
   }

   @LeaveItAlone
   public void NOTinterceptedMethod2() {
      // ...
   }
```

I imagine something like:

```
pointcut sub_nonannotated() : !execution(@LeaveItAlone * Base+.*(..));
```

But I'm certain the above is wrong.

Side question: how do I intercept specifically the constructor of the subclass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I just tried it and you apparently have it almost correct. This is what worked for me:

```
package com.snaphop.ats.util;

public aspect Blah {
    pointcut sub_nonannotated() : !execution(@LeaveItAlone * Base+.*(..));

    pointcut sub() : execution(* Base+.*(..));

    pointcut notBase() : ! execution(* Base.*(..));

    pointcut cons() : execution(public Base+.new(..)) && ! execution(public Base.new(..));


    //advice sub class methods but not annotation or parent
    Object around() : sub_nonannotated() && sub() && notBase() {
        return proceed();
    }

    //Advice subclass constructors but not Base's constructor
    Object around() : cons() {
        return proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam. Check out my solution, I think it is a little less complex.

Comment: It looks simpler. IIRC I was just banging the answer out and not optimizing it. I haven't needed to use AspectJ in a while and find the syntax for some reason confusing at times.

Answer (score 0):

Adam Gent's solution is way too complex. This pointcut is simpler and clearer:

```java
execution(!@LeaveItAlone * Base+.*(..))
```

Or alternatively, maybe you like it better (a matter of taste):

```java
execution(* Base+.*(..)) && !@annotation(LeaveItAlone)
```

P.S.: This only takes care of methods, not of constructors, which is what you asked for in your first sentence. I also includes methods of `Base` itself, not just subclasses, which probably makes sense. If you wanted a more complex thing, you can still combine my solution with the elements from Adam's.